# How to get GCE instance labels using metadata service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In the GCP console I can set labels (key=value) to instances.

How to I access that information through the metadata service (preferably using curl)?

Comment: Get the instance ID out of metadata, then access https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get.

Answer (score 2):

You can Query default vm metadata and custom metadata such as startup and shutdown scripts with `curl` like is showed in the following example :

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/image" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Also, as you mention, you can use guest attributes or custom metadata for situations where you must publish infrequent and low volume data as explained in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/manage-guest-attributes#when_to_use_guest_attributes). You can also query the metadata server to get these values as is shown below:

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/guest-attributes/**NAMESPACE**/**KEY**  -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Replace:

**NAMESPACE**: the namespace for the guest-attributes key that you want to query.

**KEY**: the path within guest-attributes from which you want to read the metadata value.

Alternatively, you can return all the guest attribute values in one request. Replace NAMESPACE with the namespace for the guest-attributes key that you want to query.

```
curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/guest-attributes/NAMESPACE/ -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```